# I can't pull up my PG database in pSequel or connect it to my Node backend

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, knex.js, psequel

I'm building my first Node.j/Express.js API with a PG database. Last night I created the database and added some table. Today I haven't been able to connect it to my backend and when I try to access in PSequel again it tells me it does not exist...

server.js

```
const express = require('express')

require('dotenv').config()

const helmet = require('helmet')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const morgan = require('morgan')

var db = require('knex')({
  client: 'pg',
  connection: {
    host : '127.0.0.1',
    user : '',
    password : '',
    database : 'my-database'
  }
});

const main = require('./controllers/main')

const app = express()

const whitelist = ['http://localhost:3001']
const corsOptions = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1 || !origin) {
      callback(null, true)
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
    }
  }
}
app.use(helmet())
app.use(cors(corsOptions))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(morgan('combined'))

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('hello world'))
app.get('/crud', (req, res) => main.getTableData(req, res, db))
app.put('/crud', (req, res) => main.putTableData(req, res, db))

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
  console.log(`app is running on port ${process.env.PORT || 3000}`)
})
```

Did I miss a step? Where should I be looking?

Comment: Was the user and password field always empty?

Answer (score 0):

> PSequel again it tells me it does not exist...

Is your database started? If you cannot connect it directly without node then this problem has nothing to do with JS part of your app.